# Ransack doesn't filter my tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ransack

I've ran into a bit of a problem. I watched `Railscasts 370` and discovered a cool new gem called `ransack`

My problem is it's not doing what I want it to do, which is to filter a table based on a search

Here is my controller

```
def index
  @search = Component.ransack(params[:q])
  @components = @search.result
end
```

And my view

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>

  <%= f.submit "Search" %>

<% end %>
```

When I typed in "Gigabyte" and clicked search, I saw the following in the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/components?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=Gigabyte&commit=Search
```

I know that this is URL syntax for a query. And it refreshes the page as well. Problem is, I see the following three results

```
Intel Core i5-4460 3.2GHz Quad-Core
Gigabyte GA-Z97X-SLI ATX LGA1150
Team Elite Plus 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
```

These were the names of the 3 items in my table. I expected only one result to return from this query.

If it helps, I've added part of my Development Logs

```
Processing by ComponentsController#index as HTML
Paramaters: {"utf8=>"checkmark", "q" => {"name_cont"=>"Gigabyte"}, "commit"=>"Search"
```

It shows up in the parameters too, so I'm completely mystified as to why my code's not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I think I found the problem but I'm not sure

I have this inside `<tbody>`

```
<tbody>
  <% Component.all.each do |c| %>

    <tr>
      <td> <strong><%= c.part %></strong> </td>
      <td> <a id="links" href="<%=c.link%>"> <%= c.name %> </a></td>
      <td> $<%= c.price %> </td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>

</tbody>
```

EDIT

Looks like that was indeed my mistake. Changing `Component.all` to `@components.each` fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change this

```
@search = Component.ransack(params[:q])
```

for this?:

```
@search = Component.search(params[:q])
```

I've been using the gem recently and probably the gem changed a little with regard the railscast